# Python DataFrame select row 3 years

Tags: python, pandas

I 5 years of stock data. and I want to select the row from the first 3 year
(2015,2016, 2017) How do I do this?

```
Date       | Year    | Month 
2015-01-02 | 2015    | 1  
2016-01-05 | 2016    | 1  
2016-01-06 | 2016    | 1  
2017-01-07 | 2017    | 1 
2018-01-07 | 2018    | 1
```

I have tired this line below:

```
ndf = df.loc[(df['Year'] == "2015") & (df['Year'] == "2016") & (df['Year'] == "2017")]
```

but it is only returning 2015.

Comment: Do you want a SQL solution (which you tagged your question with), or a python solution (which you tried to code with)?

Comment: Hi, I put the wrong tag here, this question is for python, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, that's straight-foward with `in`:

```
select *
from mytable
where year in (2015, 2016, 2017)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is returning rows for `2015`?  You have set up an `AND` condition that cannot be satisfied and should return an empty dataframe.

Please use this:

```
ndf = df.query('2015 <= Year <= 2017')
```